# Off-policy Monte Carlo Control

Tags: ds.algorithms, machine-learning, markov-chains, monte-carlo

The off-policy Monte Carlo control algorithm to learn the optimal state-value function $V^*$ is given as follows, which is obtained from Sutton's book.

[image: Off-policy monte carlo contral algorithm.]

I have three questions concerning this algorithm:

1. Why does the algorithm going backward, that is, it iterates from $t = T-1$ downwards to zero in each episode.
2. The algorithm ensures that $A_t = \pi(S_t)$ for each $t$ otherwise it jumps out of the loop. Are there any additional assumptions to guarantee this algorithm works? How can it ensure $A_t = \pi(S_t)$ as $\{ S_t, A_t, R_t\}$ is generated by policy $\mu$, which is different from $\pi$.
3. It seems weight $W$ is the importance sampling ratio. But here the target policy $\pi$ changes over time. I think the reason that $W$ is updated by
   $$ 
   W \leftarrow W \cdot \frac{1}{ \mu(A_t | S_t)}
   $$
   is because the target policy is always greedy with respect to $Q(s,a)$, which makes $\pi(A_t | S_t) = 1$. Is this correct?

Comment: You should ask these questions on [Artificial Intelligence Stack Exchange](https://ai.stackexchange.com/). Furthermore, please, if you decide to ask them there, ask 1 question per post, even if they are related. It's better to separate the questions so that users can focus on one question per post.